# Terminology of adjacent points

Tags: geometry

I know the definitions of sides and angles in standard geometry (i.e. perpendicular, parallel, adjacent, etc), but I need help defining them in terms of points. Given the following two examples, what different terms define points B in relation to point A?

## 1

```
  B
B A B
  B
```

## 2

```
B   B
  A
B   B
```

Answer (score 0):

1. East, North,,West, South ( of A).
2. North-East, North-West, South-West, South-East( of A).